# Do-Nothing Adapter accessor method

Tags: java

I've looked around a lot for help with this specific question, maybe my wording is off, if that's the case, a link would be perfect!

Here's the problem:

I have an interface with the following:

```
Product get(String prodCode);
```

I also have an abstract class implementing the interface with the following:

```
public Product get(String prodCode) { //Do nothing }
```

However, to satisfy the compiler, I have to return something (either null or a Product). My understanding is that it shouldn't return either of these things as it would no longer "do nothing".  I'm not sure how to satisfy the compiler while also doing nothing.

Comment: Don't you want to make that method `abstract` then?

Comment: In this case, what does it mean to 'do nothing' from your requirements standpoint?  What will code that is going to consume this expect?

Comment: I'm not even sure to be honest... Taken from assignment:

The Adapter must implement the “get” method and the “disconnect” method as do-nothing methods (i.e. method stubs).

Comment: As martijno said, why don't you make the method abstract?  
Instead of returning `null` you can use the [Null Object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) and return a `Product` instance with no behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your DoNothingProduct implementation would look like, but you could have a no-arg default constructor for Product that would return an immutable object with default fields set.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information from your comment, I would say that you could do either one of the following:

1. Return `null`.
2. Return a default `Product` object which has no functionality.

Returning `null` would be the simplest, but you would want to make sure that calling code protects itself from `NullPointerException`'s that could result from attempting to interact with the returned result.

If you were to do the second, a `static final` object would probably be ideal to return.

Comment: Okay, we'll try using null and we'll keep you posted. Thank you and everyone else who has answered so far.